# Home improvement for my travel agent

Tags: knowledge, visual, computer-puzzle

"Howdy, howdy! Thanks for painting my kitchen for me."

"No problem Pat. The offer of a free vacation is definitely a sweetener. Where were you going to send me?"

"It's a great tour! You visit the city which has all of the haunts of my favourite fictional character."

"And who might that be?"

"OH! Did I mention my perfect color? The manufacturer is Dulux; my favourite HGTV star guided me to it. Let me send it to you by text."

[image: Palette]

"Wow, that's a pretty broad swath of different colours. Which one did you have in mind?"

"White, of course. We were talking about where you're going!"

"Pat...is this a puzzle?"

<*click*>

---

Pat got me again. Now I'm painting a kitchen, AND I have no idea where I'm going. Can you help me figure this mess out?

---

##### HINTS

> Use the information given in the puzzle to identify the exact colours Pat sent. Or is that colors?

> Google will be your friend in this puzzle. There exist websites, one of which might be obliquely referenced, which can help you identify the manufacturer's name for a colour based on its computer representation.

> The first colour is "Frankly Scarlet", but maybe you don't give a damn.

Comment: It's a bit interesting that rot13(gur svefg vafgnapr bs gur jbeq pbybe vf fcryyrq qvssreragyl naq snibhevgr vf nyjnlf fcryyrq gung jnl)...

Comment: @oAlt That difference is 100% intentional.

Comment: The rgb values of your pixel and the colour you stated in the hint don’t match

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to look up these colors with the hex codes in the image and I haven't had any luck. The site clued in the text of the puzzle doesn't seem to give any results, and other sites I've tried match it to Racy Red (Dulux 64RR) instead.

Comment: Yeah, it's proving pretty hard to find the matching colors. I've found 1 or 2 by being lucky with search terms (3eq pbybe vf Qhyhk Benatr Objy), but it feels like I'm missing something unless the intended solve path is clicking through 80 pages of colors?

Comment: meanwhile I've managed to find all the color names but I have no idea what to do with them...

Comment: @PDT There are many different references out there, and I don't claim that all of them match. However, there is cluing in the puzzle text to identify one specific site which does provide a correlation for all colour/name pairs in the puzzle.

Comment: @Deusovi I agree the reference site does not have a good search interface to correlate codes to colours. Maybe some other tool can be used for that.

Comment: @JGibbers Looking through 80 pages of colours is certainly not the intended solution. Maybe some other tool can be used to search the reference website.

Comment: @juicifer The order of the colours is specific, and correlates with the canon of the fictional character referenced.

Comment: Very well-made and satisfying puzzle

Comment: Ah, I was so close. I also found all the color names. The second hint was helpful too and looking back I should have spotted that immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First extract the rgb for each color.

How I did it:

> I intially tried going through myperfectcolor.com directly, but that was proving too tedious. Then using https://www.easyrgb.com/en/match.php#inputFORM with the collection filter on Dulux, look up each color.
>  I double checked each color in myperfectcolor.com to make sure the hex codes match.
>  If I still couldn't find a color, I googled the hex code with `site:myperfectcolor.com` and was able to fill in some more.
>  This got me the paint color associated with each row/hex.

All together:

> A23F59 - Frankly Scarlet
>  D9807A - Rouge Red
>  D65328 - Orange Bowl? (D65427)
>  0273A8 - Blazing Blue? (0073A9)
>  A6C2B3 - Beryl Green
>  BB7219 - California Copper
>  DBE1E1 - Silver Streak
>  E9CC62 - Pacific Yellow
>  533739 - Black Russian
>  F1CF75 - Golden Bell? (F0CF75)
>  AAA9C0 - Wild Wisteria
>  8E3D49 - Afghan Red
>  The items with ? weren't exact matches.

Now taking the last unused hint from the question.

> All of these refer to Sherlock Holmes stories - which also happens to be his favourite HGTV star (this is the part that finally made it click)!
>  Frankly Scarlet - A Study in Scarlet
>  Rouge Red - The Red-Headed League
>  Orange Bowl - The Five Orange Pips
>  Regatta Bay - The Adventure of the Blue Carbuncle
>  Beryl Green - The Advensture of the Beryl Coronet
>  California Copper - The Adventure of the Copper Beeches
>  Silver Streak - The Adventure of Silver Blaze
>  Pacific Yellow - The Adventure of Yellow Face
>  Black Russian - The Adventure of Black Peter
>  Golden Bell - The Adventure of Golden Pince-Nez
>  Wild Wisteria - The Adventure of Wisteria Lodge
>  Afghan Red - The Adventure of the Red Circle

Obviously, we're going on vacation to:

> London, where all of these stories take place. And has all the haunts of his favourite fictional character (Sherlock Holmes)

Comment: So my apologies that you had so much trouble identifying the colours. I found (and checked several times) that if searching Google with "site:myperfectcolor.com dulux #xxyyzz", I got the intended answer each time. And the hex colours actually appear as text in the appopriate pages. But anyway, you got there, and the further analysis is 100% correct!

Comment: Yeah that was much easier once I figured that out! I think my problem is I started searching google with rgb (r, g, b) instead of the hex and those turned up nothing! Completely reasonable solve once I started using google primarily!

Comment: I don't get the HGTV part.

Comment: @oAlt Check out rot13(Ubyzrf ba Ubzrf). It wasn't meant to be too crucial, just indicative.